# PythonのDataframe型 から Datetime型への変換について

Tags: python, python3, pandas

質問です。python初心者で、よくわからないので、教えてください。
pandas のDataFrame内のstr型をdatetime型に一括変換し、月や日のデータを取得したいです。

DataFrame型→datetime型への変換はto_datetimeで変換できることは分かったのですが、そこから月・日のデータを抜き出す工程が分かりません。

また、一度to_datetimeで変換したものをstr型に変換する方法もご教示いただければ幸いです。

```html
<table>
<tr><th>2017-04-01 00:00</th><th>土</th></tr>
<tr><th>2017-04-01 01:00</th><th>土</th></tr>
<tr><th>2017-04-01 02:00</th><th>土</th></tr>
<tr><th>2017-04-01 03:00</th><th>土</th></tr>
<tr><th>2017-04-01 04:00</th><th>土</th></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.dt` から、 datetime 系のメソッドが使えます。

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([
    '20170401 12:00:00',
    '20170401 13:00:00',    
    '20170401 14:00:00',        
])
print(s)
print('---')

s_dt = pd.to_datetime(s)
print(s_dt)
print('---')

print(s_dt.dt.year)
print('---')

print(s_dt.dt.month)
print('---')

print(s_dt.dt.day)
print('---')
```

出力

```
0    20170401 12:00:00
1    20170401 13:00:00
2    20170401 14:00:00
dtype: object
---
0   2017-04-01 12:00:00
1   2017-04-01 13:00:00
2   2017-04-01 14:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
---
0    2017
1    2017
2    2017
dtype: int64
---
0    4
1    4
2    4
dtype: int64
---
0    1
1    1
2    1
dtype: int64
---
```

Answer (score 0):

結構時間が経っているようですが、参考までに。
元データがどういったものかわかりませんでしたので、2017年4月1日から365日分のDataFrame型を作成して、以下の手順で書き出してみました。

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#4月1日から翌年3月31日までのDataFrameを作成
date = np.array('2017-04-01', dtype=np.datetime64)
df = pd.DataFrame(date + np.arange(365),columns=['date'])

#順番に月日を書き出し
for row in range(len(df)):
    print(df['date'][row].strftime('%m/%d'))
```

最初にdatetime64の型から配列を作り、その後DataFrame型にしています。この場合は、to_datetimeを使わずにそのままcolumnの'data'からstrftime('%m'や'%d')で月や日を指定して抜き取っています。
元データが日本語表記の月（2017年4月1日）などの場合は、一度変換などする必要があります。
以下は3日分だけですが、日本語表記から変換する場合です。やっていることはほぼ一緒です。

```
date_jp=['2017年4月1日','2017年4月2日','2017年4月3日']
df_jp = pd.DataFrame(date_jp,columns=['date'])
df_jp['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_jp['date'], format='%Y年%m月%d日')
for row in range(len(df_jp)):
    print(df_jp['date'][row].strftime('%m/%d'))
```

こちらは、リストをDataFrameに変換した後、datetimeの形として認識させ、月と日をfor文で抜き出しています。